# How to change locale and storyboard programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, resources, storyboard, locale

I have two button in main storybord.
The storyboard is localized (IT and EN)
I Created a Localizable File (IT and EN)

If i start in every language the application the default locale is EN and if i start in Ita lang then it start in ITA Locale.

That's all right.

Now i want that the initial button can change and reload the storyboard in other language end load string in these language.

I found in the network this solution but that not loaded string in these language and not reload storyboard.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["it"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Answer (score 3):

To effect this edit you should close the App and relaunch